# getting null pointer exception

Tags: apex, trigger

here i want to insert some names which is having semicolon(;) in between two names iam trying to splitting code but am getting `null`

```
List<Contactsample__c> cammemlist=new List<Contactsample__c>();
Contactsample__c cs=new Contactsample__c();
String[] testArray;
if(cs !=null)
{
    String data=cs.CampaignAttended__c;
    System.debug(data);
    if(data !=null)
    {
      testArray=data.split(';');  
      System.debug(testArray);
    }
}
```

there data is showing `null` how resolve that issue

Comment: value is not their i have to insert Photography Seminar 2018;Protecting Gabon; that type of data

Comment: Your code will work if `cs.CampaignAttended__c` has values

Answer (score 3):

Before you can address the issue, you must understand the issue.

Some simple debugging is all it takes to understand the issue. Just start at the point where you have a known state, and work backwards until you find out *why* `data` is null.

Your known state here is that `data` is null. You know this because of the `System.debug(data);` line.

Now, start working backwards. Where does `data` get set?
It gets set on the line above, `String data=cs.CampaignAttended__c;`
Because `data` is null, `cs.CampaignAttended__c` must be null.

Why is `cs.CampaignAttended__c` null?
Continue to work backwards through your code.

Eventually, you reach the declaration and initialization of the `cs` variable, `Contactsample__c cs=new Contactsample__c();`

You don't set `cs.CampaignAttended__c` anywhere between initializing the `cs` variable, and when you set your `data` variable using `cs.CampaignAttended__c`. It's only natural that this variable would be null.

How you would go about making this `data` variable not be null really depends on where this snippet of code is used (and the purpose it's for). The solution here is different if you're using this in a Visualforce controller, compared to if it's being used in a trigger.

About all we can say with the information that you've given us is that your second line, `Contactsample__c cs=new Contactsample__c();`, is not what you want to do here. This variable should either be fed from the results of a query, input from a Visualforce page/Lightning component, or from a trigger context variable.

For sake of completeness, you're getting the Null Pointer Exception because `data` = null, and `null` contains no methods, attributes, or properties.

Answer (score -2):

do a null check, your code will work;

```
String data;
if(cs.CampaignAttended__c != null){
 data=cs.CampaignAttended__c;
}
```

Comment: that code is also not working it is not showing values in debug log